# Powershell / XML to TXT / adding character in result of a select -expandproperty

Tags: xml, powershell, txt

I'm trying to add character in the result or in the output of a data extraction from a XML file.

Exemple.xml :

```
<House>
<Room value=1>
</House>
```

I'm able to obtain and export to txt the value of room using:

```
[xml]$data=get-content Exemple.xml

$Room = $data.House.Room | Select -ExpandProperty value

$Room | Out-File RoomNumber.TXT
```

Content of RoomNumber.txt being "1"

I'd like to add a prefix to this result , so that this content be "Room Number 1".

I'm unable to find a method to add "Room Number " prefix in the Object $Room or in the Content of RoomNumber.txt.

Do you think there is a way to do so ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the last line:

```
$Room | Out-File RoomNumber.TXT
```

To

```
"Room Number ${Room}" | Out-File RoomNumber.TXT
```

Instead of passing the value of `$Room` directly to `Out-File`, we define a *new string* containing the value and pipe that to `Out-File`

---

If `$Room` might contain *multiple* values, I'd suggest renaming it accordingly and then use `ForEach-Object`:

```
$RoomNumbers = $data.House.Room | Select -ExpandProperty value

$RoomNumbers |ForEach-Object { "Room Number ${_}" } | Out-File RoomNumber.TXT
```

Comment: Hey, thx. It's working if only one value is returned, or for the first value of multiple response. I'll try to test around your Idea. EX : Room Numer 1 Room Numlber 2 ... instead of Room Number 1 2 ...